# Can we use refine UI without router

Tags: reactjs, uibuilder, refinejs

The [refine UI library](https://refine.dev/) is simply awesome, but most examples I saw rely on having a router and defining what path will have access to some action on the data source. But if I want just to render the Inferecer for some action of the data source in some already made UI, can we do this with refine?

To make it clearer, imagine that I want to use refine to embed the inferer so I will get code for a form for creating data on the top of an already made page and code for a table to list all data from another different data source on another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, refine can be used without the Router.
refine provides its features using React context and is completely modular. This means it can be used without any router, whether it's Next.js, Remix, React Router, or any other.

I created a simple example for you:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nostalgic-kepler-slmryt?embed=1

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice that the Inferecer has the properties action and resource to define which UI to render.